# UITableViewCell loading issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i have a UITableViewCell loading 10 images its loads the first 6, then its saying (cell != nil) so it doesnt load the remaining images, but if i remove the "if(cell==nil)" it loads all the images
am i missing something?

thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = nil;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

int section = indexPath.section;
NSMutableArray *sectionItems = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"CELL == NIL %@", cell);
    int n = ([sectionItems count]) ;
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    int i=0,f=0; 
    while (i < n)
    {
        int yy = 4 +f*74;
        for(int j=0; j<3;j++){
            Item *item = [sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];                
                int buttonX = 10;
                if (i == 0) {
                    buttonX = 10;
                }else {
                    buttonX = 203
                }

                CGRect frame;
                frame.origin.x = buttonX;
                frame.origin.y = yy;
                frame.size.width = 107;
                frame.size.height = 107;
                asyncImageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
                asyncImageView.tag = ASYNC_IMAGE_TAG;
                NSString *urlString = item.image;
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImageView];

            i++;
        }
        f = f+1;
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"cell != nill");
    asyncImageView = (AsyncImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:ASYNC_IMAGE_TAG];                     
}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
>   {
>       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>   if (cell == nil) {
>       NSLog(@"CELL == NIL %@", cell);
>        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
>       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
>       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
>   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,20,30,40);
>                   UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
>                   img.tag = IMAGE_TAG;
>   [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
>   [img release];
>   }int row = indexPath.row;
>   UIImageView *myImage = = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG];
>   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" , row]];
>   [myImage setImage:image];
>   return cell;}

UITableViewCells are cached to save memory and allocations costs (hence performance). You only create a cell once and after that you set it contents based on your index path. I've simply created an imageview in the cell and later on set an image depending on the indexpath in that cell (1.png , 2.png etc).

Read the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Sorry about the messed up code. I couldn't format it right. I hope this makes sense though.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells are re-used to save time and memory, typically, and you're using this paradigm I see.   You need to implement the cell != nil case and set up the cell to display the contents based on the indexPath.    The cell was previously used to display other content so you need to adjust all indexPath-dependent views in the non-nil cell.

Comment: do you have an example of what you mean? im totally confused, sorry and thanks for the help much appreciated